# Horrible lag / stuttering in Debian 12 KDE Plasma Wayland

Tags: debian, kde, desktop-environment, gpu

I just installed Debian 12 with KDE from live installer. Everything seems to work fine until I enter the password on login screen. When I get to the desktop (Wayland Plasma), mouse and keyboard are incredibly slow, everything is like 1 FPS.

When I log out and select X11 as the desktop session, things work fine again.

On a possibly related note, I installed Debian 11 with KDE before and got "nouveau: unknown chipset" error. I'm using RTX 3060 GPU.

I'm not even sure about the source of this issue (nouveau drivers? Wayland Plasma DE?), so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `nouveau` drivers are the "free" attempt at nvidia drivers, because as Linus says, *duck you, nvidia* - have you tried loading nVidia™ drivers

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, i did try that as well, didn't help with debian 11. haven't tried on 12 yet. but things work fine on X11 so i'm not sure the issue is related to drivers?

Comment: It *is* related to drivers because your graphics card really can't work properly with the current *nouveau*. AND you need to either sign the modules manually or disable Secure Boot in UEFI, that's all.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I just tried disabling Secure Boot. It did seem to fix it for a few seconds, but then the big lag came back :) I'm very confused.. Also I tried Cinnamon, GNOME etc. They all work fine.. The big lag is only in Wayland desktop.. I guess I'll stick with X11..

Comment: Yes, you should stick with X11 when using any new(ish) Nvidia. Wayland is still sort of experimental with Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Comment a few months later: I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers and things were working fine, but recently the audio (through DP cable to my monitor) started acting up, very low volume etc. so I reinstalled things and trying to stay away from the proprietary driver and sticking with X11.. This looks like the best solution for now..